# How to get shares count for a Photo in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, statistics, facebook-fql

I want to get comments count, likes count and shares count for a page posts. I have their IDs and I'm trying to figure something out with the Graph API or FQL, but in vain.

For regular posts I can query the `stream` FQL table and I get the `comment_info`, `like_info` structures and `shares_count` variable.

For posted photos I can query the `photo` table and I get from there `comment_info` and `like_info`, but it lacks the `shares_count`.

I tried using Graph api like that: `GET /550045508388715` and it returns a ton of information, but nothing related to share count.

I've googled that issue, but did not found any relevant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `GET /ID` use `GET /POST_ID` to get the shares count (if >1). You'll get the result as-

```
"shares": {
    "count": x
 }
```

Note- the Post ID is generally: `USERID_PHOTOID` OR`PAGEID_PHOTOID`

Comment: When I try `GET /[PAGE_ID]_[PHOTO_ID]` I get exception "Unsupported get request", for example: GET /138365596223377_550045508388715

Comment: Just now I posted a photo to your page and got the post id : `138365596223377_10151645004663611` and when I `GET` this id , I got all the relevant details. Pls confirm

Comment: Interesting, that is working for other posts, like: `GET /131722836966884_286164828189350` ... So I assume it might be facebook bug that the request sometimes fails?

Comment: Ya, I'm not sure why its failing for that particular photo. btw, you can accept the ans if that helped!

Comment: Sure, here it is. I also opened a support ticket about the issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/305796906232717?browse=external_tasks_search_results_51ff7f229c6db3e21917090

Comment: This method no longer works you just get a Deprecated as of version 2.4 exception thrown...